# Suggestion needed for uk visa 2nd attempt

Tags: united-kingdom, refusal

Respected Sir/Mam,

I have applied for uk Tire 4 visa for LSE summer schools but i have got a refusel . I need suggestions before going for secound attempt . Let me draft a picture of visa application . 
I have fully paid the accomodation as well as tution fee . I was self sponsored i got the funds from the companies where i was invested eariler . 
So what changed should i make so that i will get visa . 
If my father will be my sponsor will that be going to work ?

[image]

I will be really thankfull if i will get to know the reason s for refusal.

Comment: I've removed your first pic because it had personal identifying information. You can alter that and repost if you like, but it's the second part that matters most anyway as this has the reason for your refusal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter seems pretty clear. They found inconsistencies in your application regarding your bank statement and claims about your income. This, possibly with other circumstances, has led to the conclusion that they think you will overstay. Your best bet is to work with a professional immigration lawyer who has expertise in these matters.